# Square collision detection problem (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, button, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I know I've probably posted three questions related to this then deleted them, but thats only because I solved them before I got an answer. But, this one I can not solve and I don't believe it is that hard compared to the others. So, with out further ado, here is my problem:

So I am using Cocos2d and one of the major problem is they don't have buttons. To compensate for there lack in buttons I am trying to detect if when a touch ended did it collide with a square (the button). Here is my code:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"%f", 240-location.y);
    if (isReady == YES)
    {
        if (((240-location.y) <= (240-StartButton.position.x - 100) || -(240-location.y) >= (240-StartButton.position.x) + 100) && ((160-location.x) <= (160-StartButton.position.y) - 25 || (160-location.x) >= (160-StartButton.position.y) + 25))
        {
            NSLog(@"Coll:%f", 240-StartButton.position.x);
            CCScene *scene = [PlayScene node];
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCZoomFlipAngularTransition transitionWithDuration:2.0f scene:scene orientation:kOrientationRightOver]];
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's on purpose but it looks like some of your variables are switched around near the end.  You're comparing x against y.

Comment: @Ed Marty: Yes, it would be on purpose...

Comment: You haven't explained what's going wrong. Does it not match? Does it match when it shouldn't? Are you not getting an event at all? Also, have you set a breakpoint and stepped through it, to see what values the variables take?

Comment: Ok, whats going on wrong is that when the BOOL isReady == YES as soon as I let go of the mouse in the iPhone simulator the program the program stops automatically goes to the PlayScene scene. As you can see I am debugging using NSLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just do

```
 if (isReady == YES)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([StartButton boundingBox],location))
    {

        CCScene *scene = [PlayScene node];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCZoomFlipAngularTransition transitionWithDuration:2.0f scene:scene orientation:kOrientationRightOver]];
    }
}
```

[StartButton boundingBox] returns the CGRect of the node and
CGRectContainsPoint checks to see if the CGPoint location is inside of the button.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code out and only had to make the small change of making a variable called inverseLocation which flipped coordinates of location because of the fact the iphone is rotated while playing the game and use that in place of location.